# laravel: parameter's order in route

Tags: php, laravel

Maybe I have made such a stupid mistake.I try to put 'update' and 'insert' in a same function!

host:xxx.com

model:example.php

Route:

`Route::('example/{a}/{b}/{c}','exampleController@example')`

Controller:

```
public function example($a,$b,$c){
      if(example::where('a',$a)->first()){
           ...//update
      }else{
           ...//insert
      }
}
```

if the parameter's order is wrong,what will happen?

like: xxx.com/example/b/a/c.

If the parameter's order is right,it will compare with a.  But,by the wrong way,it will compare with b and insert a wrong data into database?

Comment: If the param is wrong it will search inside the database by the wrong value.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Are you creating a backdoor? Otherwise I don't see a logical reason to use such unsafe structure.

Comment: @DainisAbols As long as the data is properly validated, escaped and/or sanitised, I don't see any difference in safety as opposed to using any get or post form, with the possible exception of csrf.

Comment: @Joel Hinz  It messes with my head.I try to make 'update' and 'insert' in a same function!my god!

Comment: Well, it's not that weird. There's even a method called updateOrCreate which does what you want: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate